# Is there any market for data science consulting

Tags: bigdata

Is there any market for data science as service which provides service without selling software, just consulting, modelling and developing algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If there wasn't a market, the largest consulting ("Big 3") and audit ("Big 4") firms wouldn't offer and continue to be expanding their advisory services in data & analytics. The same could be said for the thousands of independent consultants who offer such services (such as those who can be found on [www.upwork.com](https://www.upwork.com/)).